# is mappings optimization problems onto neural networks still a thing?

Tags: optimization, neural-networks, discrete-mathematics

Is mappings optimization problems onto neural networks still a thing? I only found papers are written prior to 1999. These old papers mostly deal with Hopfield network, which i read is obsolete and only for theoretical properties. So is there any progress with neural networks (maybe different ones to Hopfield) and solving optimization problems (for examples combinatorial ones, like TSP, Vertex Cover, Job scheduling ects.)?

Comment: Have you checked whether anyone cites the papers you found? Which papers did you find?